# Json received from user cannot be converted to type in my webserver API

Tags: asp.net, json

I developed a web API that receives json and converts it to my predefined format & then writes it in a file.

when client is trying to send  a put request, I receive this json on server:

```
{
  "_entities": [
    {
      "_name": "wizardaccessprivilege",
      "_SourceUniqueId": "e",
      "_isIncludedInLibrary": false,
      "_isCustomEntity": false,
      "_sourceSchemaName": "WizardAccessPrivilege",
      "_isIncludedInConnection": false,
      "_uniqueId": "9",
      "_hasChanged": "",
      "_associatedLibrary": {
        "_description": "Privilege needed to access a Web-based wizard."
      },
      "_defaultLabel": "Web Wizard Access Privilege",
      "_description": "Privilege needed to access a Web-based wizard.",
      "_sourceApplication": 0,
      "_lastModifiedDate": ""
    },
    {
      "_name": "egcsapps_fcrisksubcategory",
      "_SourceUniqueId": "7",
      "_isIncludedInLibrary": false,
      "_isCustomEntity": true,
      "_sourceSchemaName": "egory",
      "_isIncludedInConnection": false,
      "_uniqueId": "f",
      "_hasChanged": "",
      "_associatedLibrary": {
        "_description": ""
      },
      "_defaultLabel": "FC Risk Subcategory",
      "_description": "",
      "_sourceApplication": 0,
      "_lastModifiedDate": ""
    }
        ]
}
```

while my object structure is:

```
{
  "_sourceClientVersionStamp": "06/05/2019 15:25:27",
  "_organizationName": null,
  "_organizationServerName": null,
  "_domain": null,
  "_workspace": null,
  "_entities": [
    {
      "_uniqueId": "gg",
      "_name": "wizardaccessprivilege",
      "_sourceSchemaName": "WizardAccessPrivilege",
      "_isCustomEntity": false,
      "_isIncludedInLibrary": false,
      "_isIncludedInConnection": false,
      "_SourceUniqueId": "e",
      "_sourceApplication": 0,
      "_sourceApplicationVersion": "5.0.0.0",
      "_defaultLabel": "Web Wizard Access Privilege",
      "_localizedLabels": null,
      "_lastModifiedDate": null,
      "_fields": null,
      "_daysSinceRecordLastModified": 0,
      "_hasChanged": null,
      "_description": "Privilege needed to access a Web-based wizard.",
      "_associatedLibrary": {
        "_library": null,
        "_libraryFolder": "/",
        "_name": null,
        "_description": ""
      },
      "_entityRelationshipSet": [],
      "_connectionSet": []
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I convert the json received from user to my type?
in the request, I have a property of my object

Note: I used this but didn't work:

```
     [Route("api/entity/UpdateConfigurationForLibrary")]
     [HttpPut]
     public void UpdateConfigurationForLibrary([FromBody] JObject data)
     {

       string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
       EntitySet dEntitiesOnly = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EntitySet>(output);
..
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Route("api/entity/UpdateConfigurationForLibrary")]
[HttpPut]
public void UpdateConfigurationForLibrary([FromBody] EntitySet entity)
{
...
}
```

In the case your JSON contains a list of objects, simply change the `[FromBody] EntitySet entity` to `[FromBody] List<EntitySet> entities`.

The framework is smart enough to map your JSON to a class type if property names are matching or if you correctly decorate your properties with `[JsonProperty("propertyName")]` attribute.

For more information regarding `[JsonProperty]` attribute, you can look [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyName.htm).